# Optimize way of putting constraints in calling methods of an existing library

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have a class library which has these following classes:

```
class A
{
    void A1() {}
    void A2() {}
}

class B
{
    void B1() {}
    void B2() {}
}

class C
{
    void C1() {}
    void C2() {}
}
```

In my client code I am doing this:

```
Class Client
{
    A objA = new A();
    objA.A1();
     // Same for other classes and their methods 

}
```

Now I have a change request  which requires me put some constraints (say RightAcess etc.) while calling the library methods. I have more than 30 classes to update. What is the optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, dont understand the question.

Comment: @leppie while calling objA.A1(); I need o check if client has RightAccess (say) to do that. One thing to consider here is all these code are already present and in production. Now we have to incorporate the constraints.

Comment: Not familiar myself, but i think [tag:PostSharp] could be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have base class for all your class and implement the same function inside the base class

```
class  BaseClass
{
    public object RightAcess()
    {
       //[Code]

    }
}

class A : BaseClass
{
  ...
}

class B : BaseClass
{
  ...
}

class C : BaseClass
{
  ...
}
```